# How to prevent the instant closing of MFC application with ActiveX ShockwaveFlash control?

Tags: c++, mfc, activex, flash

So i'm using the ShockwaveFlash ActiveX element in my MFC application to play some .SWF file.

The problem is: ShockwaveFlash element works properly only if the Adobe Flash Player ActiveX is installed in the system. I want to check programmaticaly if Adobe Flash Player ActiveX is installed and if it is not then not to use this element. But if Flash Player not installed then my program closes immediately after startup without giving me opportunity to do my check.

Is there a way to prevent it? Or is there some DLL or something i should add to my application to make my ShockwaveFlash element work on any Windows system?

Comment: What is executed last? Just step thorugh your application with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution. I shouldn't add the ShockwaveFlash element on my dialog through the Visual Studio constructor. If i will create the element through Create() method the program wouldn't close even if Flash Player is not installed.